# How do I make EpiModel run on multiple cores in R?

Tags: r, multiprocessing

I'm modelling a quite big network with EpiModel in R, and the code takes very long to run, so I want to run it on multiple cores instead of just 1. I thought this was possible in EpiModel itself, but when I try it, my code just keeps running without starting the simulations. This is the code I am using:

```
library(EpiModel)
library(parallel)
nw <- network::network.initialize(n=6000, directed=FALSE)

formation <- ~edges + concurrent
target.stats<-c(1500, 600)
coef.diss <- dissolution_coefs(dissolution=~offset(edges), duration = 1)
est <- netest(nw, formation, target.stats, coef.diss)


dx<-netdx(est, nsims=10, nsteps=122, dynamic=FALSE, ncores=4)

init <- init.net(i.num=1, r.num=0)
param <-param.net(inf.prob=0.55, act.rate=0.6, rec.rate=0.05) 
control<-control.net(type='SIR', nsteps= 122, nsims =10, ncores=4)
mainsim <- netsim(est, param, init, control)
plot(mainsim, y='si.flow')
```

When I set ncores to 1 it will run, but any other number doesn't work. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: It seems that the EpiModel package uses `doParallel` rather than `parallel` package. Do you have it installed?

Comment: @BaltazarGonzálezChávez I didn't have it installed, so I installed and loaded it but it still didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: frankly I do not see any error in your code. But some ideas that could help: the most obvious: 1: did you check that your machine has more than 1 core? a function for this is `doParallel::detectCores()`. 2: how much time are you waiting before stopping your code? sometimes with big data, the time taken for splitting the data among the cores is greater than expected. I've encounter situations where allocation of data among cores is slower than the analysis it self (but with small data, matrix of 200k cells or so).